# Disable select option based on innerhtml with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**Scenario:** User votes via HTML form for a field trip to take on a bus. There are three options:

```
    <select id="selectbox">
      <option>Berlin</option>
      <option>Munich</option>
      <option>Cologne</option>
    </select>
```

The free bus seats are stored in / read from a database: ($tour is our array keeping the free seats)

```
<table class="status">
  <tr><td>Berlin: <span id="t1">available (<?php echo $tour[0]; ?> seats)</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Munich: <span id="t2">available (<?php echo $tour[1]; ?> seats)</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cologne: <span id="t3">available (<?php echo $tour[2]; ?> seats)</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

If free seats are zero, we display a "sorry, booked out" info using vanilla JavaScript:

```
// get content of status table
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML;
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML;
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML;
var bookedout = "sorry, booked out!"

    // check if condition is met
if (t1 == "available (0 seats)") {
    document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = bookedout;
}
if (t2 == "available (0 seats)") {
    document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = bookedout ;
}
if (t3 == "available (0 seats)") {
    document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = bookedout ;
}
```

Works fine. However, now comes the part I'm a bit lost. The above condition should also delete the respective option from #selectbox **based on the option's innerHTML**. In jQuery I'd go with something like #selectbox option:contains('stringhere').

However, I wanna do it in the purest of JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: So to get it right: you want to remove for example the option Berlin from the dropdown, if there are 0 seats available. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, Ivan. Using pure JavaScript.

Comment: But why don't you check, if for example `$tour[0] === 0` and only then insert the option, if it's greater than 0? Is it absolutely necessary to remove it afterwards with js or would it work to already keep it out, as soon as you do all the inserting?

Comment: Like this:
`
<?php
    if($tour[0] !== 0) { ?>
        <tr><td>Berlin: <span id="t1">available (<?php echo $tour[0]; ?> seats)</span></td></tr>
    <?php }
?>
`

Comment: I would strongly recommend moving away from parsing content. Using a JS view model would be much safer and easier to use, in my eyes. There are plenty of easy-to-use frameworks you could use, I'd suggest *knockout.js*, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the order of the options inside the select correspond to the order inside the table element you could simply do something like this.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('selectbox');
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('status').item(0);
var rows = table.rows;
var bookedout = " sorry, booked out!";

// check whether an option is bookedout
// and save its state to a new array.
var bookedOutState = [].slice.call(rows).map(function(row) {
  var match = row.children[0].textContent.match(/\d/);
  if (+match[0] === 0) {
    row.children[0].textContent = match['input'].substr(0, match['input'].indexOf(':') + 1) + bookedout;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})

// go over the new created array and remove
// options from select according to the saved state.
bookedOutState.forEach(function(state, idx) {
  if (!state) {
    select.removeChild(select.children[idx])
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="selectbox">
  <option>Berlin</option>
  <option>Munich</option>
  <option>Cologne</option>
</select>

<table class="status">
  <tr><td>Berlin: <span id="t1">available 0 seats</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Munich: <span id="t2">available 1 seats</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cologne: <span id="t3">available 2 seats</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I the only one who completely lost faith into assuming string patterns in layout? Both answers seem to miss the point that the OP already has its data in database. The data will always parse the same way, but the layout won't... then both answers will break. We really should insist on what's his reasons of doing this. I can't figure a single use case in which an out-of-sync model is wanted behavior. IMHO, the efforts to save time on the back end may come at the price of integrity.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straight forward..

First in your `html` give vlaues to your options:

```
<select id="selectbox">
  <option>Berlin</option>
  <option>Munich</option>
  <option>Cologne</option>
</select>
```

Then in js:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("selectbox");
//function to get option values as array
function getOptionsArr() {
var optionsArray =[],options = mySelect.options; 
var i = 0, len = options.length;
// store the options value in an array
while (i < len)
{
  optionsArray.push(options[i++].value);
}
    return optionsArray;
}
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML;
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML;
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML;
var bookedout = "sorry, booked out!"

// check if condition is met
if (t1 == "available (0 seats)"){
    document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = bookedout;
    //this will get the whole parent node and child node inner text we split at : and get the value
    var textArr = document.getElementById("t1").parentElement.innerText.split(':');
 // find the index of value from our array created above and remove that option from select
 mySelect.remove(getOptionsArr().indexOf(textArr [0]))
}
//repeat the same for other
if (t2 == "available (0 seats)"){
 document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = bookedout ;
 var textArr = document.getElementById("t2").parentElement.innerText.split(':');
 mySelect.remove(getOptionsArr().indexOf(textArr [0]))
}
if (t3 == "available (0 seats)"){
document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = bookedout ;
 var textArr = document.getElementById("t3").parentElement.innerText.split(':');
 mySelect.remove(getOptionsArr().indexOf(textArr [0]))
}
```

Aditionally you can refactor it by

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("selectbox");
//function to get option values as array
function getOptionsArr() {
var optionsArray =[],options = mySelect.options; 
var i = 0, len = options.length;
// store the options value in an array
while (i < len)
{
  optionsArray.push(options[i++].value);
}
    return optionsArray;
}

var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML;
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML;
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML;
var bookedout = "sorry, booked out!"

// check if condition is met
if (t1 == "available (0 seats)"){
    doUpdateDOM("t1")
}
if (t2 == "available (0 seats)"){
doUpdateDOM("t2")
}
if (t3 == "available (0 seats)"){
doUpdateDOM("t3")
}

function doUpdateDOM(nodeID){
    document.getElementById(nodeID).innerHTML = bookedout;
    var textArr = document.getElementById(nodeID).parentElement.innerText.split(':');
 mySelect.remove(optionsArray.indexOf(textArr [0]))
}
```